# Printing a value from a list in python if the condition is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm

I am trying to perform a relatively basic operation in Python, I am trying to print a value from a list if it is a particular type of value, so for instance, print the value if it is a string type.

This is what I have so far, I believe my structuring is somewhat incorrect also as exception is also printing 5 times.

```
x = [ 1, 'string', 3, 4, 5 ]
for i in x:
     if i is type(str):
        print('item is {}'.format(i))
     else:
        print('There are no strings in the list')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if i is type(str):
```

I think you wanted:

```
if type(i) is str:
```

but even better, use:

```
if isinstance(i, str):
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that solved the first half of the if statement pulling the string from the list, however, my result is still printing 5 lines like so 

'There are no strings in the list
item is string
There are no strings in the list
There are no strings in the list
There are no strings in the list'

How would I make it so that it reads the list and ONLY returns the string value, would that be possible?

Comment: Your `else:` part refers to the `if` that is executed in every iteration of the `for` loop, so it prints the message for every item in the list that is not a string. Remove `else:` and the next line and the message will not be printed…

Comment: Thank you for that, you not only gave me the answer you epxlained the rationale behind it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print only strings try below code. else condition will be executed if if condition fails.

```
x = [ 1, 'string', 3, 4, 5 ]
for i in x:
     if type(i) is str:
        print('item is {}'.format(i))
```

or

```
x = [ 1, 'string', 3, 4, 5 ]
for i in x:
     if isinstance(i, str):
        print('item is {}'.format(i))
```